# How to run a unit testing in J2ME Midlet Project

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

Good Evening.

Can i ask some questions in J2ME ?
 1. How to run a unit test in a J2ME Midlet Project using JMunit, J2MEUnit, Unit Test ?
 2. How to run the unit test of your Application in the Emulator .

By the way, I'm Karl, i am a newbie developer in J2ME. I hope you could help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The project was migrated to 
`http://j2meunit.sourceforge.net/doc.html.`

So this will give you idea how to use it.
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Unit_testing_with_JMUnit_and_NetBeans_IDE

It's more interesting question unit test framework for AT commands